# Can't Hide Rows in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, row, hide

Have code to show or hide rows based on a value in one of the cells for that row  (In SQL Reporting Services)

I either get all the results hidden or none of the results hidden

Tried this

```
=IIF(Fields!CommodityCode.Value = "BOP",False,True)
```

Field Name is correct and `BOP` is a valid value for the field

```
=IIF(Fields!CommodityCode.Value = "BOP",False,True)
```

When the value `BOP` is in the cell then that row should show.  Any other rows where the value of that cell is `NOT BOP` should be hidden.

Comment: Try adding a filter at the `dataset` for `CommodityCode = "BOP"`.

Answer (score -1):

So the issue here is that your conditional is checking the entire dataset for `BOP` and not the specific cell.  You'll want to modify your expression to the following.

```
=IIF(ReportItems!CommodityCode.Value = "BOP",False,True)
```

The `ReportItems!` should be followed by the name of the textbox that contains the `CommodityCode` field. So you'll basically only need to replace the `CommodityCode` with the textbox name.  The `.Value` should stay there.

EDIT: Based on the comment below, it seems you simply need to add a parent group to your data that groups by `CommodityCode`.  In the `Row Groups`, right click on the details group and click `Add a parent group`.  Then, simply select the `CommodityCode` field as shown below.

[image]

After that, you usually need to remove sorting from the group properties because it adds a sorting field by default.  I typically will add a page break between groups, as well.

Comment: The name of the textbox is CommodityCode
Tried your version and got the same results as mine.
I've been using code like this to hide rows in tables for years....

Comment: @TSimon Ok, then my expression should work as you need it to.  You're using `Fields!` when you need `ReportItems!`.

Comment: If I do this
, case when [InvMaster+].CommodityCode = 'BOP' Then 'Tim' else 'Colin' end as TheCode  
In my data query I can the successfully use 
=iif(Fields!TheCode.Value = "Tim",False,True)
To Show / Hide the data

Comment: @TSimon I'm not sure what that has to do with your question?  Could you clarify why my solution doesn't work, if that's the case?  Or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have no idea why your solution doesn't work.  It seems to be a problem with the data - maybe the datatype.  If I use a CASE statement in my data query and type in the exact same values for CommodityCode then I can use my IFF statement and it works.
The datatype for CommodityCode is Char(4)
I'm trying to create three Report tables, each of which will only show a list of items that have the same CommodityCode value.  My master query generates a list of items, then I simply do a JOIN to the table that has the values for CommodityCode.

Comment: @TSimon It sounds like you might just want to use an additional row group in your tablix.  Check my answer for a new edit.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!

Comment: @TSimon great, glad I could help.  Would you mind [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that any others that find your question can reference the correct resolution?